# How to ignore a single/multiple keys of all the dictionaries while looping over a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, key

I am looping over a list of dictionaries and I have to drop/ignore either one or more keys of the each dictionary in the list and write it to a MongoDB. What is the efficient pythonic way of doing this ?

**Example:**

```
employees = [
{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10, 'salary': 10000, 'floor': 10}, 
{'name': "Mark", 'age': 5, 'salary': 12000, 'floor': 11}, 
{'name': "Pam", 'age': 7, 'salary': 9500, 'floor': 9}
]
```

Let's say I want to drop key = 'floor' or keys = ['floor', 'salary'].
Currently I am using del employees['floor'] inside the loop to delete the key and my_collection.insert_one() to simply write the dictionary into my MongoDB.

**My code:**

```
for d in employees:
    del d['floor']
    my_collection.insert_one(d)
```

Comment: If efficiency is important, don't use `insert_one()` in a loop.

Comment: Then how do you reckon this can be improved ? Form a new list of dictionaries and use insert_many() ?

Comment: Yes, reshape your data then use `insert_many()`. It still might be the case that iterating over your list of dict and using del might be faster than a comprehension but the bottleneck is `insert_one()`

Answer (score 1):

The solution you proposed is the most efficient to use since you have no control on what happens inside the method `insert_one`.

If you have more keys, just loop over them:

```py
ignored_keys = ['floor', 'salary']
for d in employees:
    for k in ignored_keys:
        del d[k]
    my_collection.insert_one(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to drop  keys = ['floor', 'salary']. You can try:

```
exclude_keys = ['salary', 'floor']
for d in employees:
    my_collection.insert_one({k: d[k] for k in set(list(d.keys())) - set(exclude_keys)})
```